# For Loop Multiplying Number

Tags: java

I need some help -

At the end of a for loop, I need to set an original value to the next multiple of the value.

This is what I have so far -

```
int originalNumber = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) { 
  originalNumber *= i;
 }
```

However, this code will not find the multiples of  1; as the multiples of 1 should be (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... ...)

This code that I have written will be (1, 1, 2, 6, 24) etc;

What is a good way to get the multiples (inside of the loop)?

Comment: Yes. since your code has lines like `.... ....` So, the correct answer would be : `............... ........ ........ .....`. _Please give verifiable code_

Comment: Apart from the ...; I removed that. That other code does not involve the variable originalNumber

Comment: @GHat well, that code doesn't build multiples, but the factorial of 10000. Or at least it would, if there was no overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for version without additional variable:

```
int originalNumber = 1;
for (int multiple = originalNumber; multiple <= 10000; multiple += originalNumber) {
    // Use multiple however you want to
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to change `originalNumber` at all - just multiply `i` by `originalNumber`:

```
int originalNumber = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    int multiple = originalNumber * i;
    // Use multiple however you want to
}
```

To get all the multiples of 2, you'd set `originalNumber` to 2, etc.

Comment: I got skeeted by 16 seconds!!

Comment: Is there an efficient way to do it using just one variable? Maybe if I change the incremention of 'i', and multiply originalNumber by i?

Comment: @GHat: Why would you want to do that? It doesn't help that it's not clear whether you're looking for 10,000 multiples (my answer) or all the multiples up to 10,000 (Roman's version). Please try to be clearer in terms of what you're trying to achieve in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int n = scanner.nextInt();
       for (int i = 1; i <= 10;  i++){
         int multiple = i * n;
         System.out.println(n + " x " + i + " = " + multiple);
        }
```

You can try this code, it prints any multiple till 10;
Your Output (stdout)
2 x 1 = 2
2 x 2 = 4
...
2 x 10 = 20